# three.js - zoom in/out complete tube geometry

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, webgl, three.js

I've created a tube geometry with data of 200 points loaded from external javascript file in JSON format. Please find the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>3d Model using HTML5 and three.js</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>          
        <input type="button" value="plot" onClick="return plotPath();" />        
        <script src="three.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Curve.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="TubeGeometry.js" type="text/javascript"></script>              
        <script src="Stats.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Detector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
        <script src="path.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script>

        // variables
        var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer, controls, stats;

        var text, plane, tube, tubeMesh, parent;

        var targetRotation = 0;
        var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;

        var mouseX = 0;
        var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        var radius = 600;
        var theta = 0;
        var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;

        function plotPath()
        {                                           
            var obj = getPath();
            var segments = 50;
            var closed = false;
            var debug = true;
            var radiusSegments = 12;
            var tube;
            var points = [];
            var x=0,y=0,z=0;                    

            for(var i=0; i<obj.path.length; i++)
            {                               
                console.log(obj.path[i].point);
                points.push(obj.path[i].point);
                extrudePath = new THREE.SplineCurve3(points);
                extrudePath.dynamic = true;

                tube = new THREE.TubeGeometry(extrudePath, segments, 2, radiusSegments, closed, debug);
                tube.dynamic = true;

                tubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(tube ,new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    color: 0x000000, side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                    opacity: 0.5, transparent: true, wireframe: true}));
                tubeMesh.__dirtyVertices = true;
                tubeMesh.dynamic = true;

                parent = new THREE.Object3D();
                parent.position.y = 100;

                if ( tube.debug ) tubeMesh.add( tube.debug );
                parent.add( tubeMesh );                                 
            }
            scene.add( tubeMesh );
            scene.add(parent);                      

            animate();                          
        } 

        init();                             

        function init(){

            // container
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );                 

            // renderer         
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setClearColorHex(0xEEEEEE, 1.0);            
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.clear();
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );                   

            // camera           
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.set(-100,75,75);                    

            // scene            
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            // light            
            scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ) );
            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
            scene.add( light ); 

            // CONTROLS
            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );               

            // Grid
            geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( - 500, 0, 0 ) );
            geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 500, 0, 0 ) );

            for ( var i = 0; i <= 20; i ++ ) {

                line = new THREE.Line( geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, opacity: 0.2 } ) );
                line.position.z = ( i * 50 ) - 500;
                scene.add( line );

                line = new THREE.Line( geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, opacity: 0.2 } ) );
                line.position.x = ( i * 50 ) - 500;
                line.rotation.y = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
                scene.add( line );
            }                   

            // projector
            projector = new THREE.Projector();

            plotPath();

            // stats
            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseover', onDocumentMouseOver, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );
            window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', mousewheel, false);
            window.addEventListener('mousewheel', mousewheel, false);
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        }

        function mousewheel(event) {

            var fovMAX = 160;
            var fovMIN = 1;

            camera.fov -= event.wheelDeltaY * 0.05;
            camera.fov = Math.max( Math.min( camera.fov, fovMAX ), fovMIN );
            camera.projectionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makePerspective(camera.fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, camera.near, camera.far);

        }

        function onWindowResize() {         
            camera.left = window.innerWidth / - 2;
            camera.right = window.innerWidth / 2;
            camera.top = window.innerHeight / 2;
            camera.bottom = window.innerHeight / - 2;
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;         

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }


        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );
            mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;     
        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
            mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.02;
        }

        function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {
            document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );
        }

        function onDocumentMouseOut( event ) {
            document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );
        }

        function onDocumentMouseOver( event ) {
            document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );
        }

        function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {
            if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                mouseXOnMouseDown = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;
            }
        }

        function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {
            if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.05;
            }
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate, renderer.domElement );
            render();
            update();
        }

        function update(){
            controls.update();          
        }

        function toCameraCoords(position) {
              return camera.matrixWorldInverse.multiplyVector3(position.clone());
            }

        function render() {                 
            tubeMesh.rotation.y += ( targetRotation - tubeMesh.rotation.y ) * 0.15;                     
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);
            camera.updateMatrixWorld();
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
        </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

When I use mouse wheel to zoom in, the camera will zoom in at starting point of the tube. How do I make the tube geometry can be zoomed completely or in other words any part of the tube can be zoomed ?

Comment: Temporarily I've achieved this by using `THREE.RollControls`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.body.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', mousewheel, false );
document.body.addEventListener( 'DOMMouseScroll', mousewheel, false ); // firefox


function mousewheel( e ) {      
    var d = ((typeof e.wheelDelta != "undefined")?(-e.wheelDelta):e.detail);
    d = 100 * ((d>0)?1:-1);

    var cPos = camera.position;
    if (isNaN(cPos.x) || isNaN(cPos.y) || isNaN(cPos.y))
      return;

    var r = cPos.x*cPos.x + cPos.y*cPos.y;
    var sqr = Math.sqrt(r);
    var sqrZ = Math.sqrt(cPos.z*cPos.z + r);


    var nx = cPos.x + ((r==0)?0:(d * cPos.x/sqr));
    var ny = cPos.y + ((r==0)?0:(d * cPos.y/sqr));
    var nz = cPos.z + ((sqrZ==0)?0:(d * cPos.z/sqrZ));

    if (isNaN(nx) || isNaN(ny) || isNaN(nz))
      return;

    cPos.x = nx;
    cPos.y = ny;
    cPos.z = nz;
}
```

or even simpler ajusting only the camera :

```
var mousewheel  = function ( e ) {
     var d = ((typeof e.wheelDelta != "undefined")?(-e.wheelDelta):e.detail);
     d = 100 * ((d>0)?1:-1);    
     var cPos = camera.position;
     if (isNaN(cPos.x) || isNaN(cPos.y) || isNaN(cPos.y)) return;

        // Your zomm limitation
        // For X axe you can add anothers limits for Y / Z axes
        if (cPos.x > _YOUR_ZOOM_MIN_X_ || cPos.x < _YOUR_ZOOM_MAX_X_ ){
           return ;
        }

   mb = d>0 ? 1.1 : 0.9;
   cPos.x = cPos.x * mb;
   cPos.y = cPos.y * mb;
   cPos.z = cPos.z * mb;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. Its working fine. How do I restrict the zoom-in/out distance/factor in this event handler ?-@foxdanni

Comment: Think about what happens when your camera is at (0,0,0). This solution isn't good.

Answer (score 4):

As with any conventional real life camera, you can change the focal length (zoom) of THREE.PerspectiveCamera by calling setLens method. I find this way very intuitive and much simplier than moving the camera to zoom in/out.

Here is the method docs in three.js:

```
/**
 * Uses Focal Length (in mm) to estimate and set FOV
 * 35mm (fullframe) camera is used if frame size is not specified;
 * Formula based on http://www.bobatkins.com/photography/technical/field_of_view.html
 */
THREE.PerspectiveCamera.prototype.setLens = function ( focalLength, frameHeight )
...
```

And here is an example usage:

```
var focalLength = 25.734; // equivalent to FOV=50
$('#scene').mousewheel(function (event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    event.preventDefault();

    focalLength += deltaY;
    camera.setLens(focalLength);
});
```

The method jQuery.fn.mousewheel is provided by [Mousewheel Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/).

Comment: what is the default value of focalLength?

Comment: @DanielBahmani, the default value is "25.734", you can deduce it from default value for field of view (FOV) in threejs which is 50. The setLens function updates FOV by simple formula: FOV = 2 arctan (x / (2f)); See source code for more info: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/af21991fc7c4e1d35d6a93031707273d937af0f9/src/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.js#L34

Comment: very convenient answer, thank you. however, `mouswheel` should be `mousewheel`