# How to zoom a three.js scene with the mouse wheel?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a simple `three.js` graphics, and I tried to use the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636370/three-js-zoom-in-out-complete-tube-geometry) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852655/zoom-in-and-zoom-out-threejs) question to make the created plot zoomable by the mouse wheel. By using the mouse wheel I would like to zoom in to the graphics or to zoom out.

Here is the complete code: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/6WyhTBhR)

However, when turning the mouse wheel nothing happens, and I do not get an error message. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: you can make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) right. (D) not pastebin

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why don't you want to use `THREE.OrbitControls()`? Have a look at [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit) and its source code. (Zoom is disabled there widh the line `controls.enableZoom = false;`)

Comment: And there is no event added for `mousewheel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
var container, camera, scene, renderer, colors;
var selected = 0;
var selectedObject;
var objects = [];

// DOM element...
container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);

// Camera...
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 150);

// Scene...
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(camera);

// Renderer...
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    clearAlpha: 1
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Scatter plot...
scatterPlot = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(scatterPlot);

// Plot some random points...
circle = new THREE.CircleGeometry(1, 20);


colors = [];
var max = 50;
var min = -50;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {         

    var object = new THREE.Mesh( circle.clone(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: new THREE.Color('black'), opacity: 0.5 } ) );
    object.position.x = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    object.position.y = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    object.position.z = 0;                 

    scene.add( object );
    objects.push( object );

}

animate();

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
document.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false );

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        //intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.set('red');
        //intersects[ 0 ].object.geometry.scale(1.1,1.1,1.1);
        if (selected === 0) {
            selected = 1;
            selectedObject = intersects[ 0 ].object;
            selectedObject.material.color.set('red');
            console.log(selectedObject.position.x);
        } else {
            selected = 0;
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            geometry.vertices.push(intersects[ 0 ].object.position);
            geometry.vertices.push(selectedObject.position);
            var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff }));
            scene.add(line);

            selectedObject.material.color.set('black');
        }

    }
}

function onWindowResize() {        
    camera.left = window.innerWidth / - 2;
    camera.right = window.innerWidth / 2;
    camera.top = window.innerHeight / 2;
    camera.bottom = window.innerHeight / - 2;
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;        

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}
function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {

    var fovMAX = 160;
    var fovMIN = 1;

    camera.fov -= event.wheelDeltaY * 0.05;
    camera.fov = Math.max( Math.min( camera.fov, fovMAX ), fovMIN );
    camera.projectionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makePerspective(camera.fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, camera.near, camera.far);

}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/54/three.js"></script>
```

In your code add event listener

`document.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false );`

Answer (score 4):

```
document.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', (event) => {
    camera.position.z +=event.deltaY/500;
});
```

Comment: Although your code answer may be right, offering an explanation on top of it would be better so others could fit it in their code or learning how to do it by themselves. For example, explaining the OP needs to bind his code in a event for it to happen would be way better already.

Answer (score 2):

The [mousewheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel) event is supported **only** in Webkit browsers.
For cross-browser compaitibility use the [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event.