# THREE.Matrix4: .makePerspective() has been redefined and has a new signature. Please check the docs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to run a working `three.js` code with the release 119 of `three.js` (instead of r79), and the previously working code now throes the following error:

```
THREE.Matrix4: .makePerspective() has been redefined and has a new signature. Please check the docs.
```

for which the is only one google hit (this question). I did check the docs but did not found any reference to `makePerspective`. So how can I fix the following code (which shows you some dots, and where I am able to zoom in and out)? See also [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353282/how-to-zoom-a-three-js-scene-with-the-mouse-wheel).

```js
container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 150);
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(camera);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  clearAlpha: 1
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x228B22, 1);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Define a standard Circle
circle = new THREE.CircleGeometry(1, 20);

var max = 50;
var min = -50;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var object = new THREE.Mesh(circle.clone(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: new THREE.Color('yellow'),
    opacity: 0.5
  }));
  object.position.x = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  object.position.y = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  object.position.z = 0;
  scene.add(object);
}

document.addEventListener('wheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);

function onDocumentMouseWheel(event) {
  console.log("mousewheel");
  var fovMAX = 100;
  var fovMIN = 1;
  camera.fov -= event.wheelDeltaY * 0.05;
  camera.fov = Math.max(Math.min(camera.fov, fovMAX), fovMIN);
  camera.projectionMatrix = (new THREE.Matrix4()).makePerspective(camera.fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, camera.near, camera.far);
}


animate();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r119/three.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd just click through to the Matrix4 class, then through to [`Matrix4.makePerspective`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Matrix4.makePerspective)... Either way, it looks like you shouldn't call it by yourself; just call [`PerspectiveCamera.updateProjectionMatrix()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.updateProjectionMatrix):

```js
container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 150);
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(camera);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  clearAlpha: 1
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x228B22, 1);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Define a standard Circle
circle = new THREE.CircleGeometry(1, 20);

var max = 50;
var min = -50;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var object = new THREE.Mesh(circle.clone(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: new THREE.Color('yellow'),
    opacity: 0.5
  }));
  object.position.x = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  object.position.y = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  object.position.z = 0;
  scene.add(object);
}

document.addEventListener('wheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);

function onDocumentMouseWheel(event) {
  var fovMAX = 100;
  var fovMIN = 1;
  camera.fov -= event.wheelDeltaY * 0.05;
  camera.fov = Math.max(Math.min(camera.fov, fovMAX), fovMIN);
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}


animate();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r119/three.min.js"></script>
</body>
```